# Как ссылочный тип хранится в стеке ?

Tags: c#, стек

Доброго времени суток! Если структура (не упакованная) как значимый тип которая живёт обычно в стеке, но может хранить ссылочный тип (например `string` или `enum`) тогда получается когда в стеке выделяется память под структуру и её поля, туда же заносятся ссылочные типы или только ссылки, а сами ссылочные хранятся в куче?

Comment: @SergeySharper вам не надоело несколько раз спрашивать одно и то же ? Я вам уже неоднократно отвечал, что **ссылочные типы всегда хранятся в куче**.   Типы-значения могут храниться в стеке, но могут быть и в куче. Собственно, в этом утверждении кроются ответы на  все ваши вопросы. Неужели это столь сложно понять? 

И еще - enum - это не ссылочный тип. Это тип-значение

Answer (score 8):

Надо вам [Рихтера](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7425674/) почитать.
ReferenceType всегда в куче. Иногда бывает наоборот когда ValueType в кучу попадает - это называется упаковка, но ссылочный тип никак в стек не попадёт (это невозможно хотя бы потому, что невозможно заранее вычислить размер).

Да, в полях структуры ссылки, а ссылки в стеке (но сами объекты в куче).

Comment: Плюсую. Кстати у Рихтера есть более новое издание. [Вот оно][1]

[1]:http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21236101/

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov, благодаря вашему короткому ответу я понял что такое упаковка. Люто плюсую.

Comment: @SoloMio: Не вполне правильно поняли: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: >>>ссылочный тип вполне имеет право быть в стеке

Вы имеете ввиду его ссылку?

Comment: @mister: Нет, значение. Вы всё же почитайте текст по ссылке.

Comment: @VladD: мой англ конечно желает лучшего, но прямого подтверждения я не вычитал в статье (допускаю конечно, что недопонял что-либо). Выходит данный ответ не правильный, судя по вашему комментарию? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, в котором ссылочный тип хранится в стеке или как это можно "пощупать"?

Comment: @mister: идея в том, что оптимизатор имеет полное положить объект в стек, если он сможет доказать, что за пределами фрейма объект не виден. Обратно, структура обязана быть расположена в куче, если ссылка на неё уходит за пределы фрейма (например, в виде closure некоторой лямбда-функции).

Единственное существенное различие между классами и структурами — семантика равенства и присваивания, вот что говорит статья. Стек или не стек — это как оптимизатор решит.

Рихтер прав, конечно, но он описывает подробности имплементации текущей версии компилятора. Новая версия может оптимизировать по-другому

Comment: @VladD: спасибо